# MongoDB configuration in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

All data I found on the Internet is about CakePHP V2. In V3 I can't configure MongoDB with cakePHP 3. I dont know how to configure datasource for mongoDB.
My Default Databse Configuration is as follows:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'users',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ]
]
```

Comment: There is no mongodb datasource in cake 3

Comment: then what should i do now???

Comment: Well, there isn't much that can be done about it, wait until someone creates a MongoDB datasource, create your own MongoDB datasource, don't use CakePHP 3 for projects that need to use MongoDB, or switch to a different DBMS.

Comment: so it seems that i have to switch to cake 2?

Comment: Well, if you _must_ use MongoDB, then yes, until someone creates a MongoDB source for 3.x, you'd have to use 2.x

Comment: It's been quite a long time since this post was marked as resolved. Thought any future visitors will be interested in pre-built connector hosted on github @ https://github.com/lewestopher/cakephp-monga

Comment: Very nice , Thanks for your help. @Fr0zenFyr

Comment: Very nice effort. Thanks @Fr0zenFyr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a solution but will give you an insight of cakePHP 3 with mongoDB.
There is no support for mongodb datasource for cakePHP 3 as for now.The most you can do is create a new one Like `ichikaway` did for cakePHP 2. You can use that if you want [Link Here](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb). Fingers are crossed that someone will take an initiative and built one. You can go through the presentation of `ichikaway` at cakefest and get an insight for the cakePHP 2 plugin for mongodb [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqDGkyG19f8)

Edit-1: New plugin developed by `lewestopher` please feel free to checkout the url for further information [cakephp-monga](https://github.com/lewestopher/cakephp-monga). I haven't used it yet but it's worth a try, Nice initiation. 
Edit-2: Just an update that another datasource is also available by `tiaguinho` [mongodb-cakephp3](https://github.com/tiaguinho/mongodb-cakephp3)

Comment: You might be happy to know that Wes King had released an MIT licensed plugin for this @ https://github.com/lewestopher/cakephp-monga

Comment: thanks @Fr0zenFyr for the link, just edited the answer so that it can help others as well.

Comment: I get the error Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found
File /var/www/cakephpmonga/vendor/league/monga/src/League/Monga/Connection.php
Line: 54 on cakephp-monga installation and run.