# EAV vs Schema changes vs Json?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, entity-attribute-value

I know this is well travelled ground but after thorough searching I still can't find a question that matches my requirements.

I'm looking to make a flexible system which allows users to define their own custom fields. E.g, some users of certain departments could require an NI number/separate passcode etc.

It currently uses MySQL (open to suggestions if this isn't ideal) a-top the CakePHP 3 Framework.

This works well with just a couple of tables so far (e.g, just users) but as the system grows many other entities will need their own custom fields too which will mean more tables which are basically the same.

I'm also concerned about data integrity - currently values go into a 'value' column which allows any data and the validation happens on the app which I appreciate might not be ideal.

There's obviously also a performance cost. Could I perhaps have an automatically created flat-file version like Magento does?

In light of this I did wonder about changing to a system where the custom data goes into a JSON array within the database but worry this might hold me back in future.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend is to go for a no-sql database like mongo-db. That would make it easier for handeling custom document fields. As far as fetching the data and sending to UI of the app , JSON is just fine (in case you are fetching from JS and not rendering in backend)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion georoot. I've heard of MongoDB before but it looks like there is no data driver for it in CakePHP 3 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711631/mongodb-configuration-in-cakephp-3-x) - is there any alternatives I could use?